# Is unique_ptr faster than raw pointer? C++

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, benchmarking, unique-ptr

I was experimenting with the benchmarking here and found weird results.
Apparently creating and deleting raw pointer is slower (according to my measurements of course) than creating `unique_ptr`, how is this possible?

```
struct deleter 
{
    template<typename T>
    void operator()(T* ptr) 
    {
        delete ptr;
    }
};

void BM_rawPtr(benchmark::State& state)
{
    deleter d;
    for (auto _ : state)
    {
        int* p = new int(0);
        d(p);
    }
    state.SetItemsProcessed(state.iterations());
}


void BM_uniquePtr(benchmark::State& state)
{
    deleter d;
    for (auto _ : state)
    {
        std::unique_ptr<int, deleter> ptr(new int(0), d);
    }
    state.SetItemsProcessed(state.iterations());
}

BENCHMARK(BM_rawPtr);
BENCHMARK(BM_uniquePtr);
BENCHMARK_MAIN();
```

This gave me weird results:

[image]

I don't want to claim nonsense like "`unique_ptr` is faster than raw pointer".
Clearly I have missed some point here, does this ring a bell to anyone?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What compiler? Did you enable optimizations?

Comment: May be try an empty loop to have an idea of what a full optimized out timing look like

Comment: With optimizations enabled, I expect unique_ptr to be comparable in performance to raw pointer.  I'd be very surprised if it was significantly different (unless there were extenuating circumstances, such as having a standard C++ library with opt-in safety instrumentation enabled).  Without optimizations enabled, performance differences are irrelevant.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, Visual Studio 2019, Language standard c++20, Maximum Optimization (Favor Speed) (/O2)

Comment: I concur with Eljay, I wouldn't expect any performance hit from std::unique_ptr over raw pointers. And I'd take the benefits of unique_ptr over raw pointers any day :)

Comment: if the compiler can tell that there are no reads to an object in a scope... it is free to optimize the entire object out. Long story short you're testing against an empty loop. Check your assembly output, it's likely the unique pointer is being removed completely

Comment: One minor difference, is that you copy `d` in every iteration when using a unique_ptr. Don't see how it can affect the result, or what can be assumed by the compiler because of it, but it is a difference.

Comment: Did you check the same, but in reverse order (unique_ptr first)? Could be potentially the overhrad of single allocation from OS, and then all remaining `new` calls use that memory.

Comment: Wrong @Mgetz, empty loop is like 0.1 ns

Comment: @EduardRostomyan check your assembly, AS-IF applies in all cases in C++

Comment: You need to check the generated code to ensure lines like `int* p = new int(0); d(p);` aren't optimized away as they have no observable effect.  `std::unique_ptr<int, deleter> ptr(new int(0), d);` is also a candidate for optimization removal.

Comment: Guys, I did check, if they were optimized away, the raw pointer wouldn't be slower.
The results are identical when I put REPEAT(benchmark::DoNotOptimize(p);); inside the loop. So non of the variables are optimized away. @RichardCritten

Comment: @Yksisarvinen, I did, no improvements. So the guess that memory layout affects in this case not the case I believe.

Comment: Compiles (with changes see [mcve]) to no code for clang and gcc- live - https://godbolt.org/z/4WGMcbhMv  Benchmarking is hard.

Comment: Try putting `benchmark::DoNotOptimize(p);` and `benchmark::DoNotOptimize(ptr);` to prevent the compiler from optimizing away the pointers. I tried to benchmark your code using [quickbench.com](https://quick-bench.com/q/lQeCghuNmxBp8Tq0SOMy8TDudxw). Clearly, you can see, with no optimizations, the raw pointer performs faster. With optimizations, however, both are equivalent. (Assuming no overhead in memory allocation by the OS.)

Comment: @Ruks, I tried that, see 3 comments above.

Comment: Equal speed with and without the deleter: https://quick-bench.com/q/mdFDMA1FHO2w_XXI87s6IBBP-Pg, https://quick-bench.com/q/13VKz1Q2LbKSV-49UI9nd77239k

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is unique_ptr faster than row pointer?

No.

> how is this possible?

Benchmarking is difficult. It is possible to measure differences that are caused by incidental differences in memory layout.